# RESTful web service returns JSON object but missing fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

I have a simple restful WS on top of a jpa entity created using the net beans wizards and hosted in glassfish 3.1.2.

When calling the WS only fields with data are returned. Null value fields are omitted from the Jason or XML.

I have tried using @xmlelement(required=true) but this is ignored.

Where should I begin to investigate or is this a simple setting that needs to be applied.

Thanks all hints welcome

Comment: Why would you want fields with no data to be returned?

Comment: We are using knockoutjs and binding based on the generated Jason object. Whilst we could craft the binding I investigating how much development resource is required in each tier of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add on @Maxim Shostuin answer: 
Think of the following scenario: 
A. someone serializes your object (with null field). 
B. this stirng is sent to a client that performs deserialization. 
C. Since there is no indication for the null field there, the object created will contain
the default value for the field (0 for int, null for non primitive) which in your case is null. 
So this shows you this is the correct behavior. 
I also encountered this issue at [Ovirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project, 
 where I stored json serialization of some entities, and then these entities got changed in their structures, when I deserialized, I did not have errors, the new fields simply got null values, 
 and I believe this is a correct behavior.